# WPF bind visibility of element to another element with attached property of specifc value

Tags: wpf, binding, attached-properties

I have the following xaml code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="b2v" />
</Window.Resources>
```

I would like to bind the visibility of a RichTextBox to the check state of a CheckBox.

```
<RichTextBox Visibility="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=chk,Converter={StaticResource b2v}}" />
```

No problem so far. But the problem is that my CheckBox has no Name property (I can't give it a name because it is copied over time).

Due to that I have an attached property for the CheckBox

```
<CheckBox local:MyUIElementAttributes.AttachedElementType="TitleCheckbox"/>
```

Now I would like to use this attached property to identify the CheckBox that the visibility of my RichTextBox is to be bound to.

How can I do that? I have to bind to the attached property and have to check the value of that to set the visibility.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to use the value of your `Attached Property` as the value of the `Binding.ElementName` property. From the [`Binding.ElementName Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) page at MSDN:

> **Property Value**
>
> The value of the Name property or x:Name Directive of the element of interest. You can refer to elements in code only if they are registered to the appropriate NameScope through RegisterName. For more information, see [WPF XAML Namescopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx).

Having read this and the linked page, it *seems* as though you can use the `NameScope.RegisterName` method instead of setting the `Name` property. You *should* then be able to refer to the name set with this method in the `Binding.ElementName` property without issue.

> Disclaimer: I have not tried this before and *could* be mistaken.